# Android Studio java.io.EOFException on Build

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

after made no modification i hit the following error when i Build my app (not Execute):

```
java.io.EOFException
> java.io.EOFException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.maybeEndOfStream(KryoBackedDecoder.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readSmallInt(KryoBackedDecoder.java:135)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.DefaultReadContext.readSmallInt(Contexts.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.codecs.BindingsBackedCodec.decode(BindingsBackedCodec.kt:57)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.DefaultReadContext.read(Contexts.kt:259)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.fingerprint.ConfigurationCacheFingerprintChecker.checkBuildScopedFingerprint(ConfigurationCacheFingerprintChecker.kt:58)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.fingerprint.ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController.checkBuildScopedFingerprint(ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController.kt:243)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$checkBuildScopedFingerprint$1.invokeSuspend(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:450)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$checkBuildScopedFingerprint$1.invoke(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$checkBuildScopedFingerprint$1.invoke(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$readFingerprintFile$1$1.invokeSuspend(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:469)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$readFingerprintFile$1$1.invoke(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$readFingerprintFile$1$1.invoke(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheIO$withReadContextFor$1$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(ConfigurationCacheIO.kt:248)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheIO$withReadContextFor$1$1$1$1.invoke(ConfigurationCacheIO.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheIO$withReadContextFor$1$1$1$1.invoke(ConfigurationCacheIO.kt)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.RunningKt$runReadOperation$2.invokeSuspend(Running.kt:34)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlin.coroutines.ContinuationKt.startCoroutine(Continuation.kt:115)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.RunningKt.runToCompletion(Running.kt:56)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.RunningKt.runReadOperation(Running.kt:33)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheIO.withReadContextFor$configuration_cache(ConfigurationCacheIO.kt:247)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.readFingerprintFile(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:467)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.checkBuildScopedFingerprint(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:448)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.checkFingerprintAgainstLoadedProperties(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:430)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.checkFingerprint(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:418)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.access$checkFingerprint(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:54)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$checkFingerprint$1.invoke(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:267)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache$checkFingerprint$1.invoke(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:260)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheRepository$StoreImpl$useForStateLoad$2.invoke(ConfigurationCacheRepository.kt:164)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheRepository$StoreImpl$useForStateLoad$2.invoke(ConfigurationCacheRepository.kt:163)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheRepository$withExclusiveAccessToCache$1.create(ConfigurationCacheRepository.kt:244)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:191)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:188)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheRepository.withExclusiveAccessToCache(ConfigurationCacheRepository.kt:242)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheRepository.access$withExclusiveAccessToCache(ConfigurationCacheRepository.kt:46)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheRepository$StoreImpl.useForStateLoad(ConfigurationCacheRepository.kt:163)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.checkFingerprint(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:260)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.determineCacheAction(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:213)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultConfigurationCache.initializeCacheEntry(DefaultConfigurationCache.kt:116)
    at org.gradle.configurationcache.ConfigurationCacheBuildTreeLifecycleControllerFactory.createRootBuildController(ConfigurationCacheBuildTreeLifecycleControllerFactory.kt:48)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:73)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.BuildStateFactory.createRootBuild(BuildStateFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.createRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:91)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:181)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:355)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readInt(Input.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readSmallInt(KryoBackedDecoder.java:133)
    ... 104 more
```

Android Studio Mac version 2022.1.1 Patch 2.

Kotlin version 1.8.

Gradle version 7.4.2.

No modification after last completed build, last time executed in emulator, then builded again then error happened.
I can't recognize where problem is since i'm not using kryo library.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following method worked for me.

1. Delete the internal 'build' folder
2. Subsequently press 'Ctrl + F9' or click 'Build' -> 'Build Project'

[image: Internal 'build' folder structure]